# Is it possible to call java/scala libraries from scalajs?

Tags: scala.js

I understand `scalajs` compiles to `javascript` so I can reuse `javascript` libraries.  Is there anyway to reuse `java` libraries as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short of reimplementing them in Scala.js, no, it is not possible to reuse Java libraries in Scala.js.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. It seems your question deserves a full separate question rather than just a comment.

Comment: i meant to edit my previous comment but hit delete. I was just wanting you to clarify why it is not possible to have plain `Scala` libraries be reused in `Scala.js`. I think it is possible, just not very clean always. I may post an answer on how, but basically the [discouraged, structural types](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/interoperability/sjs-defined-js-classes.html) provide at least a _possibility_ for `Scala.js` objects to interoperate with a reused Scala library that supports structural types. Structural types are largely unpopular, but it is _possible_ and can save in a pinch.

Comment: This question is originally about reusing *Java* libraries, but you're talking about reusing *Scala* libraries. That's completely different! So I'm still confused, and more convinced that you should write a separate question.

Comment: note that the title is: `Is it possible to call java/scala libraries from scalajs?`